# How can I access c# code inside VBA?

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I want to reference c# code inside VBA. I did this following

1. Created .dll and .tlb files from visual studio for c# project. I also checked "Register for COM interop" in the project properties.
2. Now I went to VBA editor in excel Developer tab and then from Tools -> Reference, I added the **.tlb** file.

Now when I tried to use the c# class by creating an instance, it failed to recognize the class. Error- User Type not defined

```
Dim obj As Parser.Form1
Set obj = New Parser.Form1
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please suggest solution. I am a newbee to .NET and VBA

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a .net library method from vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954001/calling-a-net-library-method-from-vba)

Comment: Voting to close as a dupe of this question, answered by yours truly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954001/calling-a-net-library-method-from-vba