# Using VBA to query information in a Microsoft Dynamcis CRM 2011 or ASPX

Tags: mysql, database, vba, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am currently trying to figure out if it is possible to query information from a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 (or alternatively the aspx) using VBA. I have checked out a few videos about web scraping and retrieving information from an aspx, but i have fallen at the first hurdle as I am unable to inspect the HTML code, or click any hyerlinks to bring me to the correct page.
Basically, I am looking to create a macro which will search a Project Number "Primary Key" and return project details from related fields. I know it is alot to ask given the vague information above, but can anyone point me in the right direction? any good tutorials or the like online?

Comment: Google for .Net and VBA interoperability to get an idea what you could do. A topic on this can be found on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954001/calling-a-net-library-method-from-vba. For .Net many examples of querying CRM can be found. As an alternative you can also consider using the OData endpoint of Dynamics CRM, which can be accessed with common web techniques.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, it is very appreciated. It all seems over my head at the minute, but hopefully it will make sense after some research!

Answer (score 0):

VBA can't be used :-(
You can use available API, You can make ASp.Net pages with C# behind them for that
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334607.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I noticed that I can export a dynamic worksheet with the information I need. So may be I can retrieve information from the exported document instead.